# Why is my array printing object locations and not the value?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, mkannotation

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import Contacts

class RunDetail: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

let runName: String?
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
let user: String
let distance: Int
let time: Int

init(runName: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, user: String, distance: Int, time: Int)   {

    self.runName = runName
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.user = user
    self.distance = distance
    self.time = time

}

var title: String?   {

    return runName

}

var subtitle: String?   {

    return ("Distance: \(distance)m in \(time) seconds, completed by \(user)")

   }

}
```

This is from a view controller:

```
var runs = [RunDetail]()
func test()  {

    databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]  {

            let childDict = child.value as? [String: Any]
            let name = childDict?["name"] as? String
            let rundistance = childDict?["distance"] as? Int
            let runtime = childDict?["time"] as? Int
            let runuser = childDict?["user"] as? String
            let runlat = childDict?["startLat"] as? Double
            let runlong = childDict?["startLong"] as? Double
            let runcoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: runlat!, longitude: runlong!)

            let runDet = RunDetail(runName: name!, coordinate: runcoordinate, user: runuser!, distance: rundistance!, time: runtime!)
            self.runs.append(runDet)
            print(self.runs)


        }
    })

}
```

I know the array will be printed at each iteration of the loop, but I want that to see if it is working properly. The issue is, I'm expecting the array to print the actual values of what I'm adding. Here is an example of what I am getting as an output at the last iteration of the loop after running test():

```
[<Sprint3.RunDetail: 0x608000ecbd00>, <Sprint3.RunDetail: 0x6080010c07e0>, <Sprint3.RunDetail: 0x6080010c0850>, <Sprint3.RunDetail: 0x6080010c08c0>, <Sprint3.RunDetail: 0x6080010c0930>, <Sprint3.RunDetail: 0x6080010c0a10>]
```

Why is it returning what I believe is the location of the value and not the value itself? The goal is that the array is holding a bunch of MKAnnotations and I will be able to display them easily by just adding each annotation through the array 'runs'. Is it because RunDetail is an instance of MKAnnotation as well? Printing the array is not required, but it makes it hard to test my data and make sure I am getting the correct results.

Comment: Did you try `print(self.runs.description)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `override` one of from the `description` or `debugDescription`s `var`. As `RunDetail` is your custom class, you are responsible for writing any `description` for your class. The examples are below:

```
override var description : String { 
    return "the values in String you want to be printed"  //Make a meaningful String with the values that you want to be printed
}

override var debugDescription : String { 
    return "the values in String you want to be printed"  //Make a meaningful String with the values that you want to be printed
}
```

Then inside your loop, just use `print(self.runs.description)` to print out.

Comment: ah that makes sense, ill try it out